# Lightning arrester sharing earthing with surge arrester

Tags: grounding, surge-protection

Is it ok for lightening arrester and surge arrester to share common earthing - that is, to use a common wire and electrode?

Is it OK for the lightening arrester earthing electrode to be close (1 or 2 feet) to household earthing/ grounding electrode?

Context for the question:

A planned household solar power generation installation (location India) shown below (without the lightning arrester):

[image: Solar PV array with net metering]

Comment: This entire topic is dangerous. There are significant books on just this. I'm no expert, having only glanced through one of them. But I recall that there are four distinct "rings" of protection against lightening and that the outer-most is there to protect the next inner ring, which is there to protect the next one, etc. The needs of each are different. At the final ring you have the usual protection against fire, shock, etc. that all homes should hope to have. You'll want good, ***experienced*** advice here. I know my advice should be treated with extreme suspicion.

Comment: I agree with @jonk above. However, I will add my own thoughts.  A lightning strike can be in the 1000s of amps. Even a good earthing electrode will have a resistance to ground measured in ohms. The result could be 1000s of volts between the electrical clamp on the electrode and ground!

Comment: @MathK There's an old National Electrical Code rule (NEC) of *"25 ohms or less"* for the copper ground. Canada has a *"1 ohm or less"* specified for substations. (These are from memory.) A good quality, brand new copper stake ground in the US will be about 4 Ohms or less. It ages, though. In 10 years that will be perhaps 4 times higher or more. A Ufer ground (rebar in concrete foundation) will likely be less and will stay that way for much longer. But the 25 Ohm rule says that a few thousand amp will mean x-ray radiation levels for the voltage. The arcing itself beaming out harmful x-rays.

Comment: @MathK There is so much to consider in designing a system to successfully withstand a nearby lightning strike. But gas discharge is certainly an important part of it. And taking the arc-overs in steps is also important. (Series strings of gas-discharge modules, for example.) It's a rocket-science of sorts. I'm very interested in learning how to design for it. It's kind of exciting, the idea of actually ***managing*** a lightning strike! But I'm ignorant. Hopefully, someone really smart on the topic will chip in.

Comment: @MathK I remember reading [this chapter from Feynman](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_09.html) where he mentions "*The total electric current reaching the earth’s surface at any time is very nearly constant at 1800 amperes. This current, of course, is 'positive' — it carries plus charges to the earth. So we have a voltage supply of 400,000 volts with a current of 1800 amperes—a power of 700 megawatts!*" A single bolt may transfer 30 Coulombs of charge!

Comment: Assuming you are in the US you can talk to your local electrical inspector and see what he will approve. In my area if it is not approved insurance does not cover any damage that may be caused by a fault. You can look in the NEC and see what is there.

Comment: I'm in India - generally for small projects such as mine, whatever the installer does is accepted by the inspectors. In this case I'm doubtful about the installer's suggestion, hence the question.

Comment: I wonder if this question should be asked in the DIY forum. I believe this kind of thing is dealt with in the US based on NFPA 780.

Comment: I helped install a lightning arrest system at one point and for grounding they used both ground rods and large area zigzag loops of thick copper wire under the foundation.  I'm not sure about belowground, but all aboveground parts of the lightning arrest system were separated and they had a heck of a lot of extra grounding, not just a few rods or plates.  Ideally the rod is supposed to bleed off the clouds before they build enough energy for a strike.